# Find value cycles in time series data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a large time-series > 5 million rows, the values in time series fluctuate randomly between 2-10:

A small section of time-series:

[image]

I want to identify a certain pattern from this time series, pattern:

when the value of pct_change is >= threshold " T " I want to raise a flag that says reading begins

if the value of pct_change is >= T or < T and !=0 after reading begins flag has been raised then a reading continue flag should be raised until a zero is encountered

if a zero is encountered then a reading stop flag should be raised if the value of pct_change is < T after this flag has been raised then a not reading flag should be raised.

I want to write a function that can tell me how many times and for what duration this happened.

If we take a threshold T of 4 and use pct_change from the example data screenshot then the output that I want is :

The main goal behind this is to find how many times this cycle is repeating for different thresholds.

To generate sample data :

```
import pandas as pd

a = [2,3,4,2,0,14,5,6,3,2,0,4,5,7,8,10,4,0,5,6,7,10,7,6,4,2,0,1,2,5,6]
idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=len(a), freq="H")
ts = pd.Series(a, index=idx)
dd = pd.DataFrame()
dd['pct_change'] =ts
dd.head()
```

Can you please suggest an efficient way of doing it?

Output that I want if threshold 'T' is >= 4 :

[image]

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") . We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

First, keep only interesting data (>= T | == 0):

```
threshold = 4
df = dd.loc[dd["pct_change"].ge(threshold) | dd["pct_change"].eq(0)]
```

```
>>> df
                     pct_change
2018-01-01 02:00:00           4  # group 0, end=2018-01-01 04:00:00
2018-01-01 04:00:00           0
2018-01-01 05:00:00          14  # group 1, end=2018-01-01 10:00:00
2018-01-01 06:00:00           5
2018-01-01 07:00:00           6
2018-01-01 10:00:00           0
2018-01-01 11:00:00           4  # group 2, end=2018-01-01 17:00:00
2018-01-01 12:00:00           5
2018-01-01 13:00:00           7
2018-01-01 14:00:00           8
2018-01-01 15:00:00          10
2018-01-01 16:00:00           4
2018-01-01 17:00:00           0
2018-01-01 18:00:00           5  # group 3, end=2018-01-02 02:00:00
2018-01-01 19:00:00           6
2018-01-01 20:00:00           7
2018-01-01 21:00:00          10
2018-01-01 22:00:00           7
2018-01-01 23:00:00           6
2018-01-02 00:00:00           4
2018-01-02 02:00:00           0
2018-01-02 05:00:00           5  # group 4, end=2018-01-02 06:00:00
2018-01-02 06:00:00           6
```

Then, create wanting groups:

```
groups = df["pct_change"].eq(0).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
```

```
>>> groups
2018-01-01 02:00:00    0  # group 0
2018-01-01 04:00:00    0
2018-01-01 05:00:00    1  # group 1
2018-01-01 06:00:00    1
2018-01-01 07:00:00    1
2018-01-01 10:00:00    1
2018-01-01 11:00:00    2  # group 2
2018-01-01 12:00:00    2
2018-01-01 13:00:00    2
2018-01-01 14:00:00    2
2018-01-01 15:00:00    2
2018-01-01 16:00:00    2
2018-01-01 17:00:00    2
2018-01-01 18:00:00    3  # group 3
2018-01-01 19:00:00    3
2018-01-01 20:00:00    3
2018-01-01 21:00:00    3
2018-01-01 22:00:00    3
2018-01-01 23:00:00    3
2018-01-02 00:00:00    3
2018-01-02 02:00:00    3
2018-01-02 05:00:00    4  # group 4
2018-01-02 06:00:00    4
Name: pct_change, dtype: object
```

Finally, use groups to output result:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(groups) \
                     .apply(lambda x: (x.index[0], x.index[-1])) \
                    .tolist(), columns=["StartTime", "EndTime"])
```

```
>>> out
            StartTime             EndTime
0 2018-01-01 02:00:00 2018-01-01 04:00:00  # group 0
1 2018-01-01 05:00:00 2018-01-01 10:00:00  # group 1
2 2018-01-01 11:00:00 2018-01-01 17:00:00  # group 2
3 2018-01-01 18:00:00 2018-01-02 02:00:00  # group 3
4 2018-01-02 05:00:00 2018-01-02 06:00:00  # group 4
```

**Bonus**

There are some case where you have to remove groups:

- The first pct value is 0
- Two or more consecutive pct value is 0

To remove them:

```
out = out[~out["StartTime"].eq(out["EndTime"])]
```

Comment: Have you tested the solution to your question?